Can I use an environment nested inside an argument?
The argument #5 could contain a latex environment like \itemize or formatting like \textbf or \textit.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xstring} % For string manipulation

% Define a new data structure to store news items
\newcounter{newsid}
\def\newsdata{}

% Define a command to add news items
\newcommand{\addnews}[5]{% date, title, source, tags, content
    \stepcounter{newsid}
    \edef\newsdata{\newsdata\noexpand\newsitem{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
}

% Define a command to display news items by tag
\newcommand{\displaynewsbytag}[1]{% tag
    \section{#1}
    \foreach \d/\t/\s/\g/\c in \newsdata {%
        \foreach \tag in \g {%
            \IfSubStr{\tag}{#1}{
                \subsection{\t}
                \textbf{Date:} \d \\
                \textbf{Source:} \s \\
                \textbf{Tags:} \g \\
                \vspace{0.5em}
                \c \\
                \vspace{1em}
            }{}
        }
    }
}

% Macro to define a news item for internal storage
\newcommand{\newsitem}[5]{#1/#2/#3/{#4}/#5,}

\title{Daily News Collection}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Add news items
    \addnews{2024-05-25}{News Title 1}{Newspaper A}{Economy, Environment}{\begin{itemize}
            \item Here is a bullet point.
            \item Another bullet point.
    \end{itemize}}
    \addnews{2024-05-25}{News Title 2}{Newspaper B}{Women Empowerment, Economy}{Here is the summary of the news article 2.}
    \addnews{2024-05-24}{News Title 3}{Newspaper C}{Environment}{Here is the summary of the news article 3.}
    \addnews{2024-05-23}{News Title 4}{Newspaper D}{Economy}{Here is the summary of the news article 4.}
    
    % Display news items by tag
    \displaynewsbytag{Economy}
    \displaynewsbytag{Women Empowerment}
    \displaynewsbytag{Environment}
    
\end{document}

Is it possible?
\addnews{2024-05-25}{News Title 1}{Newspaper A}{Economy, Environment}{\begin{itemize}
            \item Here is a bullet point.
            \item Another bullet point.
    \end{itemize}}

It shows a warning

Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 53.


please always add a [mre], including a class etc. so that we can reproduce your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Apologies. Please check now. So far I know that arguments only take plain text as input. If it is not possible, is there any way around it?
